# Access octave struct member from c++ api

Tags: c++, c++11, octave

I have to create a c++ program to read and manipulate an image using the Octave C++ API. The image is in .mat binary format.
To read the file in octave I use

```
S = load("/path/to/file", "-mat", "house") // house is the var name
```

and `S` is of type scalar structure.

To read the file in c++ I have a created the following function

```
namespace oc = octave;

void octave_read(char* file, std::vector<double>& v , const std::string& variable) {
    oc::interpreter inter {};
    try {
        inter.initialize_history (false);
        inter.initialize_load_path (false);
        inter.initialize();
        if (! inter.initialized ()){
            std::cerr << "Octave interpreter initialization failed!"
            << std::endl;
            exit (1);
        }
        octave_value_list in{};
        in(0) = file;
        in(1) ="-mat";
        in(2) = variable;
        octave_value_list out = Fload(inter, in, 1);
        // this should be replaced to get the actual values of the variable
        for (int i = 0; i < out(0).length(); ++i) {
            std::cout<< "got here" <<std::endl;
            std::cout<< out(0).class_name();
        }
    }  catch (const octave::exit_exception& ex){
        std::cerr << "Octave interpreter exited with status = "
                  << ex.exit_status () << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const octave::execution_exception& e)    {
        std::cerr << "error encountered in Octave evaluator!" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << e.info();
    }
}
```

which utilizes the load builtin load function of Octave. It reads the file and saves the result to `out` variable but I cannot access the `house` variable-member of the struct. I also tried converting `out(0)` to `octave_scalar_struct` but still no luck. So my question is how can I access the variable of the `out(0)` struct from the Octave C++ API?

Edit:
Note: the variable of the struct should be an array of doubles

Comment: Just from walking through the code, it seems to me that Fload relies on [load](https://octave.org/doxygen/stable/d4/d5a/load-save_8cc_source.html#l01153) which also calls [load_vars](https://octave.org/doxygen/stable/d4/d5a/load-save_8cc_source.html#l00379); this references an octave_scalar_map rather than an octave_scalar_struct. Maybe that will work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subsref` to extract variable "house":

```
octave_value val = out(0).subsref(".", {ovl("house")});
Matrix mat = val.matrix_value ();
```

It is assumed that `house` is a matrix. You can instead get it as a N-dimensional array of double values:

```
NDArray arr = val.array_value ();
```

Other data types are also available.